# Why am I getting an undefined when I try to access db.collection in the code below?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

```
var express = require('express');
var GoogleUrl = require('google-url');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var app = express();
var db;
var googleUrl = new GoogleUrl({key: '********'});
var PORT = 8080;


mongo.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/url-shortener', function(err, db){
   if(err){
       throw new Error('Database failed to connect');
   } else{
       console.log('Successfully connected to MongoDB on port 27017');
   }
   db.createCollection('sites', {
      autoIndexID: true 
   });
   db.close();
});

app.use(favicon(__dirname+'/public/favicon.ico'));


app.get('/new/*', function(req, res){
   console.log('This is the url: '+req.params[0]);
   googleUrl.shorten(req.params[0], function(err, shortUrl){
       if(err){
           console.log(err);
       }else{
           console.log(shortUrl);
       }
       check_db(req.params[0], shortUrl, db);
   });
});


app.listen(PORT, function(){
    console.log('Express listening on: '+PORT);
});
```

> //When I try to call my db.collection method here, I get an error
>   statement saying that TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of
>   undefined.

```
function check_db(longUrl, shortUrl, db){
    db.collection('sites').findOne({
        'longUrl': longUrl, 
        'shortUrl': shortUrl
    }, function(err, result){
        if(err){
            throw new Error(err);
        }if(result){
            console.log('This site already exists on the database');
        }else{
            console.log('This site does not exist on the database');
        }
    });
}
```

> I have made sure to declare my db variable globally and I even passed
>   it to the check_db function to make sure.
>
> Following is the error statement in full
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined
>       at check_db (/home/ubuntu/workspace/urlshortener/server.js:45:7)
>       at /home/ubuntu/workspace/urlshortener/server.js:35:8
>       at /home/ubuntu/workspace/urlshortener/node_modules/google-url/lib/google.js:18:7
>       at Immediate._onImmediate (/home/ubuntu/workspace/urlshortener/node_modules/google-url/lib/google.js:163:11)
>       at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)

Comment: i can't see where you are initializing the variable `db`

Comment: Db is a global variable in mongo shell, but not in node js.

Comment: @Mr.7 - I am initializing it in the sixth line of the program.

Comment: @notionquest - What do you mean? How can it be a global variable inside of a mongo shell but not in node js

Comment: dont put apikeys in shared code ‍♂️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your db is undefined. You have to assign it to the created db in your connect callback.

```
mongo.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/url-shortener', function(err, newDb){
   if(err){
       throw new Error('Database failed to connect');
   } else{
       console.log('Successfully connected to MongoDB on port 27017');
   }
   db = newDb; // ADD THIS
   db.createCollection('sites', {
      autoIndexID: true 
   });
   // db.close();
});
```

EDIT:

as pointed out by the answer of @notionquest, you also have to keep the connection open until your requests are done.

Comment: So your solution worked! Thanks! But, I have a different problem now in my check_db function where there is no console statement being logged by the app. It enters the findOne method, but does not enter the callback. I have tried running it through a debugger, but no luck!

Answer (score 1):

You get the mongo connection on the following line :-

```
mongo.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/url-shortener', function(err, db){
```

Then closed the connection inside that:-

```
db.close();
```

Please comment this close statement and try. I think it should work.

If you would like to use the same connection (which is a good practice), please don't close the connection. You can close the connection at the end.